# Sublime Text 3 Multiple selection

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to do this Multiple selection with Sublime on Mac:

I can do it easily with Textmate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/htjDk.gif

But did not found how to do it with Sublime.

Answer (score 3):

With text highlighted (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> for all text): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> will allow you to modify text on all lines simultaneously.

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection

Answer (score 3):

Select the required text and press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> multiple times.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it. Does not recreate the same behavior as in the screenshot.